# cucumber devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, cucumber, cancan

I'm trying to write a feature to test an authentication of a user model (devise + cancan). To the User can be attributed different roles. The point is to test functionality when authenticated user has one of the roles ("admin" or "registered"). By default, user is created as having role "registered".  I'm using [rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber/) and [Authorization and users management in rails](http://edapx.com/2012/04/18/authorization-and-user-management-in-rails/) as a start.

So I've got the following tables

```
sqlite> .tables
roles_users        users                 views           
roles              schema_migrations
```

app/model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
     before_save :setup_role
...
 def setup_role 
    if self.role_ids.empty?     
      self.role_ids = 2 # corresponds to "registered"
    end
  end
end
```

app/model/role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

features/user_authentication.feature

```
   Scenario: User signs in successfully
    Given I exist as a user
```

features/step_definitions/user_definition.rb

```
...
def create_user
  create_visitor
  delete_user
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, @visitor)
end     
    ...
Given /^I exist as a user$/ do
 create_user
end
```

spec/factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'changeme'
    password_confirmation 'changeme'
  end
  factory :role do
    role_id 2 
  end
end
```

When I run cucumber, I get **an error**

```
Scenario: User signs in successfully      # features/user_authentication.feature:12
Given I exist as a user                 # features/step_definitions/user_definition.rb:58
  Couldn't find Role with id=2 (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
  ./app/models/user.rb:21:in `setup_role'
```

I suppose that I must be missing some factory or association, but I'm new to the topic and have  not managed to find out how to resolve the problem. I will appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your FactoryGirl definition to

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'example@example.com'
    password 'changeme'
    password_confirmation 'changeme'
  end
  factory :role do
    id 2 
    name 'registered'
  end
end
```

`Role` has `id`, and this becomes `role_id` in any reference. So you need to setup a `Role` with just `id`.